# How can I send a constant stream of the camera module to the screen?

Tags: raspbian, camera

Right now if I type:

```
raspistill -t 60000
```

I can see the image on screen for 60 seconds, but I just want to show what the camera sees at all times. I am connected via HDMI.

Comment: As far as I can tell you need to use the raspivid command raspivid -t 999999 -o – | nc [insert the IP address of the client] 5001 to generate an H.264 stream as detailed in the intro post http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/3890

Answer (score 4):

You can just pipe raspivid straight to mplayer, rather than using nc to send it across the network:

```
raspivid -fps 20 -t 99999999 -o - | mplayer -fps 20 -cache 1024 -
```

You should be able to change fps to get a suitable frame rate, but both fps numbers should be the same to make the video output match the recording.

Comment: do you know how to pipe to php to stream via http?