# Show *modified* video from camera on screen

Tags: video, camera, streaming-video, media

There are many tutorials how to show video from camera on screen (like [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7609/how-can-i-send-a-constant-stream-of-the-camera-module-to-the-screen) one). I need to **modify** video stream with simple but custom filter. Stream may be low-res, so CPU should have enough juice.

What is the best way to modify live video stream?

Comment: Self comment - Raspberry camera board seems to do some DMA to framebuffer trick, bypassing CPU. May bu quite hard then.